# Dictionary put into Array gets shredded

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to send data to the server. Server waits from my this structure among other:

```
{
...
"card": [
           {
              "child": {...},
              "parent":{...}
           },
           {
              "child": {...},
              "parent":{...}
           }
        ], 
        [...],
        [...]
}
```

So it should be Dictionary (`{...}`) placed into another Dictionary (`{"child":..., "parent":...}`), placed into an Array (`"card": []`), and this array is a cell, the final API JSON contains many of such cells.

I realize this structure by something like this:

```
NSDictionary *card = @{@"key1" : @"val1", @"key2" : @"val2", @"key3" : @"val3"};
NSDictionary *pair = @{@"parent" : card, @"child" : card};
NSArray *cards = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: pair, pair, nil];
```

After this I add *cards* Array into Dictionary with other auth data and send it to the server:

```
[self.userAuthData setObject: cards forKey:@"card"];
```

And I see in the server logs that data was shredded: http://monosnap.com/image/UbLPA0AK0eotAvG12o1ML4702xy0aj.png

But, if I use Dictionary *cards* instead of Array *cards*, everything is ok: http://monosnap.com/image/IzenpFc3Gik01UYhyRYtGFHmxBpCpC.png

What's wrong with idea to store Dictionary in an Array? Why it gets shredded?

Comment: Your example at the top is malformed. Your `"card"` value is specified as `[...],[...],[...]` instead of as an array `[{...}, {...}, {...}]`.

Comment: Ian, by “at the top” you mean example of structure waited by the server? Right, it should be [...], [...], [...]. I don't know why the server programmer called it *card* but it contains many *cards* actually.

Comment: How is the `userAuthData` dictionary defined?

Comment: Yes, I mean the "structure waited by the server". It needs to have a container around the array elements. You're *still* missing it.

Comment: l'L'l userAuthData before setting `cards` for `@"card"` key, is formed this way:
`self.userAuthData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:
                            @{@"app_token" :            @"xxx",
                              @"user" : @{
                                          @"id" :       self.dbUser.server_id,
                                          @"token" :    self.dbUser.token
                                         },
                              @"synced":                @0
                             }];`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, answer is here: [AFNetworking posts JSON arrays as multiple single-entry dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344580/afnetworking-posts-json-arrays-as-multiple-single-entry-dictionaries)

I just added a line in my `ApiClient.m`

```
_sharedClient.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```