# Sending HTTP Body as string using AFNetworking or NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, afnetworking

I am consuming a POST web service which take the Parameter like this

```
jsonObj = {
  "id" : 0,
  "platform" : 1,
  "method" : "Home"
}
```

So how to send it in parameter I am using AFNetworking to consume webservice.

My Code

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:ContentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"id",[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],@"platform",API_HomeProductList,@"method", nil];
 NSDictionary *param =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dic,@"jsonObj", nil];
[manager POST:APIMainURL parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil]]; //
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@",json);
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

}];
```

When I see my parameter after converting it to Json by AFNetworking it become that is valid json

```
{
  "jsonObj" = {
    "id" : 0,
    "platform" : 1,
    "method" : "Home"
  }
}
```

but And I get some error cause my web service take

```
jsonObj = {
   "id" : 0,
   "platform" : 1,
   "method" : "Home"
 }
```

as parameter

So Please suggest me how to send

```
jsonObj = {
   "id" : 0,
   "platform" : 1,
   "method" : "Home"
}
```

in Parameter.

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344580/afnetworking-posts-json-arrays-as-multiple-single-entry-dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood something. Your web takes

```
jsonObj={
   "id" : 0,
   "platform" : 1,
   "method" : "Home"
 }
```

it means you need create a json

```
{
   "id" : 0,
   "platform" : 1,
   "method" : "Home"
 }
```

So, you just need remove 1 line code

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:ContentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSDictionary *param = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"id",[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],@"platform",API_HomeProductList,@"method", nil];
// NSDictionary *param =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dic,@"jsonObj", nil]; /// remove this
[manager POST:APIMainURL parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil]]; //
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@",json);
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

}];
```

Comment: no my webservice takes jsonObj={
   "id" : 0,
   "platform" : 1,
   "method" : "Home"
 }  if i do as instruct shows error . I have to pas inner json by apending jsonObj= .