# How can I POST an NSArray of NSDictionaries inside an NSDictionary without problems?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I do know how to do this, it's fairly simple.

The problem is that it doesn't work.

Here's the function I use to POST the data:

```
- (void)updateWebsitesUsingParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters;
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager POST:@"http://notreal/updateWebsites.php"
       parameters:parameters
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

              NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

              //...
          }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

              //...
          }];
}
```

Here are the parameters:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"type" : @"0",
                             @"credentials" : @{@"email" : @"notreal@gmail.com", @"password" : @"notreal"},
                             @"device" : @{@"ID" : @"8588107756600540", @"numberOfSessions" : @"0", @"name" : @"Nick's iMac"},
                             @"websites" : @[@{@"title" : @"Google", @"URL" : @"http://www.google.com"}, @{@"title" : @"Yahoo", @"URL" : @"http://www.yahoo.com"}]};
```

Here's what gets saved in the MySQL field:

```
[{URL = "http://www.google.com";},{title = Google;},{URL = "http://www.yahoo.com";},{title = Yahoo;}]
```

**THIS IS CRAZY!**

1. I have successfully saved JSON of an array of dictionaries with multiple attributes inside a dictionary inside a MySQL field --**or in short what I'm trying to do here**-- using a PHP script for a different purpose and it works, no problem.
2. I use the same PHP code to save it to the MySQL field so IT'S NOT PHP'S FAULT.
3. All other save / retrieve functions I have made using AFNetworking work perfectly.

This works:

```
@[@{@"title" : @"Google"}, @{@"title" : @"Yahoo"}]
```

This doesn't:

```
@[@{@"title" : @"Google", @"URL" : @"http://www.google.com"}, @{@"title" : @"Yahoo", @"URL" : @"http://www.yahoo.com"}]
```

Here's the response:

```
{
    websites =     (
                {
            URL = "http://www.google.com";
        },
                {
            title = Google;
        },
                {
            URL = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        },
                {
            title = Yahoo;
        }
    );
}
```

**INSANE!**

For some reason, it breaks down if I add an extra attribute.

This must be an **AFNetworking** bug because it makes no sense.

EDIT:

I could:

1. Make two MySQL fields: websiteTitles, websiteURLs.
2. Save it as one string: "Google;http://www.google.com" and then separate it but that defeats the purpose of using JSON.
3. Send the parameters chopped in half: websteTitles, websiteURLs

All are hideous, any ideas?

EDIT 2:

I run a few tests:

It doesn't matter if the array has 1 or 2 items it still behaves like this.

I tried what **rob180** suggested and --as expected-- it's AFNetwokring's fault:

```
{
    websites =     (
                {
            URL = "http://www.google.com";
        },
                {
            title = Google;
        },
                {
            URL = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        },
                {
            title = Yahoo;
        }
    );
}
```

This is the actual server response of what has been send from the app, no mysql in the middle.

EDIT 3:

```
REQUEST: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7f9352d467e0> { URL: http://notreal/updateWebsites.php }
```

The **HTTPBody** looks like this:

```
<63726564 656e7469 616c735b ... 653d30>
```

How can I decode this?

Also, I'm using an **AFHTTPRequestSerializer**. Maybe, if I change it to **AFJSONRequestSerializer** it will fix the problem but I really don't want to since I have written many methods this way.

Comment: try sending the parameters that you send to the server as a response. That way you can see if the problem is on iOS or or PHP.

Comment: have you tried to set requestSerializer?

Comment: No, I didn't need to set the requestSerializer for more than 10 methods. Now, perhaps I need it but how? What setting will fix this?

Comment: what do you mean when you say that it does not work? Have you tried to log the request on the server side to see what you are getting or are you getting nothing?

Comment: Can you print out your requests body on the iOS side and add it to your question? The request should be in the operation ( `operation.request` )

Comment: How can I decode the request body?

Comment: Any ideas? I'm stuck here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"query string parameterization is simply not a reliable way of encoding nested data structures. This is why all modern web frameworks have built-in conveniences that automatically decode incoming JSON into parameters."* - **Mattt Thompson**

So, ***JSON*** it is...

Parameters:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"websites" : @[@{@"Title" : @"Google", @"URL" : @"http://www.google.com"}, @{@"Title" : @"Yahoo", @"URL" : @"http://www.yahoo.com"}]};
```

Send:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:@"http://server/path/file.php"
       parameters:parameters
          success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

              NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
          }
          failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
          }];
```

Retrieve:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

$response = ["URLOfTheSecondWebsite" => $request['websites'][1]['URL']];

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Response:

```
{
    URL = "http://yahoo.com";
}
```

All done!

*Pure gold.*

Comment: This answer should be pinned on the homepage. It reliefs newbies like me of all frustration so easily... :')

Comment: Justice will be served. The truth will outshine the sparkling world of sciolism my fellow overflower.

Answer (score 2):

update function `AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue`

change

```
     for (id nestedValue in array) {
         [mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[]", key], nestedValue)];
     }
```

to

```
     int i = 0;
     for (id nestedValue in array) {
         [mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[%d]", key, i++], nestedValue)];
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with `AFHTTPSessionManager`.
Unfortunately you have to switch to `AFJSONRequestSerializer` to send array of dictionaries:

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

`AFJSONRequestSerializer` sets **application/json** content-type and server that expects JSON will successfully accept request parameters while `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` will always have **text/html** content-type in header even if you set it explicitly.